# Central European Standard Time instead of CET for Date.prototype.toString()

Tags: javascript, date

I have strange behavior with toString method of Date in JavaScript.

My colleagues have:

```
const event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Tue Aug 19 1975 23:15:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

And me:

```
const event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Tue Aug 19 1975 23:15:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Standard Time)
```

So, I have the standard clock time with clear words and I don't want it.

Comment: What do you see if both systems also do `console.log(navigator.language)`?

Comment: @Pointy I have en-GB and fr-FR

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try out `toLocaleDateString` to gain consistent results. E.g. `event.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {timeZoneName:"long",weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour:'numeric', minute:'numeric', second: 'numeric'})`

Comment: That won't necessarily produce consistent results either. The Intl object essentially defines an API without specifying exactly what the results should be. There is no standard for timezone names or abbreviations, so there will likely be differences in implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using different browsers or browser versions. The output of [`Date.prototype.toString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-todatestring) in ES2018 is not fully specified. As you can see in the specification about the the [TimeZoneString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-timezoneestring):

> Let tzName be an implementation-defined string that is either the empty string or the string-concatenation of the code unit 0x0020 (SPACE), the code unit 0x0028 (LEFT PARENTHESIS), an **implementation-dependent timezone name**, and the code unit 0x0029 (RIGHT PARENTHESIS).

The current versions of Firefox show `(CET)`, Chrome `(Central European Standard Time)`, and Safari `(CEST)`.

Comment: Okay, that's work. But my question is not reflect correctly my situation. Due to this, I have some failed unit tests with Jest. Any idea?

Comment: @mickaelw I don't know what you are testing but you should not test the date formatting. Instead test the actual value, e.g. the unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: I agree, it's a props in a snapshot. You give me an idea ;)